# Kendo UI. Grid autoload data

Tags: kendo-grid, paging, loaddata

I am trying to use grid grouping and paging together. When users collapse a data group, I would like the grid to re-calculate the number of pages, and to display additional data records if they now can fit on the current page. Is there a way to force the data store to load additional data for the page?

```
    var configuration = {
    dataSource: {
        data: data.data,
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: modelMetadata
            }
        },
        group: {
            field: 'AssetType',
            aggregates: [
                {field: 'AssetType', aggregate: 'count'}
            ]
        },
        pageSize: 100
    },
    resizable: true,
    sortable: {
        mode: "single",
        allowUnsort: false
    },
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        buttonCount: 5
    },
    selectable: "multiple cell",
    filterable: {
        mode: "row"
    },
    columnMenu: true,
    columns: columnsMetadata,
    change: onChange

};

gridElement.kendoGrid($.extend({
    dataBound: function(e) {
        var columns = e.sender.columns;
        var dataItems = e.sender._data;

        for(index in classStyle){
            var columnIndex = 1;
            for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
                if(columns[j].field == index){
                    break;
                }
                columnIndex++;
            }
            for (var j = 0; j < dataItems.length; j++) {
                var units = dataItems[j].get(index);
                var row = e.sender.tbody.find("[data-uid='" + dataItems[j].uid + "']");
                var cell = row.children().eq(columnIndex);
                cell.addClass(getCellColorClass(units, index));
            }
        }
        renderButton();


    }
}, configuration));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to attempt this, post the code you try, and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Comment: I Think you should use Master-Detail grid for this issue . when collapse a group , a grid under that record display additional records.